# How to make it possible to add business hours in Full Calendar by the user from the client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I looking the solution for Full Calendar to add the ability to add business time by the client itself. Currently I found and implemented only hard coded version on full calendar side.

```
selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
    eventConstraint: 'businessHours',
    businessHours: [
        {
            dow: [1, 2, 3], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
            start: '09:00',
            end: '18:00'
        },
        {
            dow: [4, 5], // Thursday, Friday
            start: '09:00',
            end: '18:00'
        }
    ],
```

There is how it looks on calendar, but it is hard coded version, without possibility to add or edit by user on the client side.

[image]

Maybe advise,some external libraries with setting schedule with business hours on Full Calendar.

Comment: Any option can be updated client-side - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options

Comment: @ADyson thank you, set option I would try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add input fields in your html, then associate the fields values to a variables, like this:
html

```
 <label for="startHour1">start hour: </label><br />
          <input type="text" id="startHour1" name="startHour1" /><br />
 <label for="endHour1">end hour: </label><br />
          <input type="text" id="endHour1" name="endHour1" /><br />
```

Javascript

```
var starthour = document.getElementById("startHour").value;

selectConstraint: 'businessHours',
    eventConstraint: 'businessHours',
    businessHours: [
        {
            dow: [1, 2, 3], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
            start: starthour1 ,
            end: endhour1 
         },
        {
            dow: [4, 5], // Thursday, Friday
            start: starthour2 ,
            end: endhour2 
        }
    ],
```

Hope this help!